# Is there a way for one Apps Script to call another, but in the context of a different user?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-script-api

I have written thousands of lines of Apps Scripts in an internal enterprise setting, but have been wracking my brain on this without any success for some time. Here's the use case:

- App Script #1 is run by users in our organization with Calendar read/write permissions. In order to operate correctly, however, it requires access to certain data that can only be accessed by a separate user with different permissions.
- App Script #2 is run as this second user, and serves up an API endpoint via doPost() or doGet() that returns the requested information.

For security reasons it is not possible to grant user #1 the full permissions required for user #2, hence the desire for user #2 to expose an API that provides only a very specific set of information to user #1.

The most intuitive solution would appear to be for user #2 to deploy an Apps Script with the "execute the app as" field set to "me", and the "Who has access to the app" field set to the organization's GSuite domain (for security reasons this must be restricted to within the organization).

However if user #1 then tries to hit that endpoint using UrlFetchApp, the request will fail (I believe with an HTTP 403) since the request does include a session token to prove that the request originates from within the same GSuite organization. Google does not seem to provide a way to generate such a session token; attempting to set an "Authorization" header with the value "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() does not work.

I have also tried using the Apps Script API to have user #1 execute the script which was deployed by user #2, however the Apps Script API makes it clear that scripts can only be executed in the context of the calling user.

I've also read separately that Google Apps Scripts do not play well with service accounts (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763096).

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Have you tried `doPost()` instead of `doGet()`? 2. How is Apps script#1 executed by user1? Button? Menu?

Comment: @TheMaster - I haven't seen a different between POST and GET requests. Script #1 is executed as a time-based trigger. (Side note: Script #1 CAN run script #2 as a different user if it's invoked as an AJAX request in the web browser, since that request includes the correct session token. But the requirement here is that script #1 can call script #2 on the server-side.)

Comment: Wonder if you can use [identity token](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken) in the request or exchange it for a session token somewhere.

Comment: Also [edit] to provide the list of scopes available to the script. Try adding profile and identity and full drive access.  May be then getOAuthToken will work.

Comment: @TheMaster Interesting, hadn't considered that. Unfortunately I tried setting the "bearer" header to the identity token without any luck.

Comment: I'm sure the identity token won't work in the auth header. But it may work as some other field or you may be able to exchange it for a session  token somewhere. How? I don't know. Regardless, What're the list of scopes available? Have you added profile and drive scope?

Comment: Scopes for the user trying to call script #2 via UrlFetchApp are pretty standard - profile, url fetching, and calendar access. Drive access won't be feasible since this is a calendar management app and we don't want the script to have access to each users' drive.

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script/blob/master/README.md#share-project-of-web-apps-with-client-users). If you need to access via urlfetch, you'd need access to the script being executed and thus drive scope. Alternatively, provide anonymous access from script#2 but rollout your own authorization/authentication in #2 without relying on inbuilt auth flow.